# How can you make a join clause displaying (ingredient1,ingredient2) from the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, self-join

I have 4 tables, from which 2 are necessary for this problem:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Ingredient_sets
(
    recipe_id NUMBER(3,0),
    ingred_id NUMBER(3,0), 
    quantity NUMBER(5,2), 
    um VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL), 
    comments VARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE Ingredient 
(
    ingred_id NUMBER(3,0), 
    ingredient VARCHAR2(30)
);
```

I have to make a join statement. It should display ingredient1, ingredient2, where the ingredients are in the same recipe (so `recipe_id` is the same), have the same unit of measurement (`um`), and the same quantity.

The result-pair should appear only once!

`ingred_id` is the primary key in the `Ingredient` table and foreign key in the `Ingredient_sets` table:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Ingredient
    MODIFY (CONSTRAINT ingred_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (ingred_id));

ALTER TABLE Ingredient_sets
    MODIFY (CONSTRAINT ingred_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (ingred_id) 
            REFERENCES Ingredient(ingred_id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

`Recipe_id` is the primary key for its table.

Until now I tried different join statements, but nothing is working

Comment: Please post the not working code and an explanation of not working.

Comment: I have removed the tag spam here; only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Tag spamming doesn't help us help you, as every dialect of SQL is different; sometimes *very* different. Though this is certainly not SQL Server, and the above is not valid T-SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a self-join on equal recipe_id & um & quantity.
And also on a higher (or lower) ingred_id.
Then you get the duo's only once.

**Sample data**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Ingredient 
> (
>     ingred_id NUMBER(3,0),
>     ingredient VARCHAR2(30), 
>     CONSTRAINT ingred_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (ingred_id)
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE Ingredient_sets
> (
>     recipe_id NUMBER(3,0),
>     ingred_id NUMBER(3,0), 
>     quantity NUMBER(5,2), 
>     um VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL, 
>     comments VARCHAR2(100), 
>     CONSTRAINT ingred_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (ingred_id) 
>             REFERENCES Ingredient(ingred_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
> );
>
> INSERT ALL
> INTO Ingredient VALUES (1, 'Butter')
> INTO Ingredient VALUES (2, 'Milk')
> INTO Ingredient VALUES (3, 'Egg')
> SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
>
> INSERT INTO Ingredient_sets 
> (recipe_id, ingred_id, quantity, um, comments) 
> SELECT 1, 1, 20.2, 'gram', 'greasy stuff' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
> SELECT 1, 2, 20.2, 'gram', 'liquid stuff' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
> SELECT 1, 3, 2.0, 'piece', 'slimey stuff' FROM DUAL
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> select 
>   set1.recipe_id
> , set1.um
> , set1.quantity
> , set1.ingred_id as ingred_id1
> , ing1.ingredient as ingredient1
> , set2.ingred_id as ingred_id2
> , ing2.ingredient as ingredient2
> from Ingredient_sets set1
> join Ingredient_sets set2
>   on set2.recipe_id = set1.recipe_id
>  and set2.um = set1.um
>  and set2.quantity = set1.quantity
>  and set2.ingred_id > set1.ingred_id
> left join Ingredient ing1 on ing1.ingred_id = set1.ingred_id
> left join Ingredient ing2 on ing2.ingred_id = set2.ingred_id
> ```
>
> ```
> RECIPE_ID | UM   | QUANTITY | INGRED_ID1 | INGREDIENT1 | INGRED_ID2 | INGREDIENT2
> --------: | :--- | -------: | ---------: | :---------- | ---------: | :----------
>         1 | gram |     20.2 |          1 | Butter      |          2 | Milk
> ```

Or use a `COUNT OVER` to filter those that don't have unique um & quantity per set.

> ```
> select *
> from
> (
>   select 
>     ingset.*
>   , ing.ingredient
>   , count(*) over (partition by recipe_id, um, quantity) as same
>   from Ingredient_sets ingset
>   left join Ingredient ing on ing.ingred_id = ingset.ingred_id
> ) q
> where same > 1
> order by recipe_id, um, quantity
> ```
>
> ```
> RECIPE_ID | INGRED_ID | QUANTITY | UM   | COMMENTS     | INGREDIENT | SAME
> --------: | --------: | -------: | :--- | :----------- | :--------- | ---:
>         1 |         1 |     20.2 | gram | greasy stuff | Butter     |    2
>         1 |         2 |     20.2 | gram | liquid stuff | Milk       |    2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3a9b09955628c0d90299a79b6105cad4)*

Comment: Thank you very much it is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

If the table `Ingredient_sets` had a primary key the solution would be simpler. Without it, the query you can use `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates. The query can look like:

```
select distinct a.recipe_id, a.ingred_id, a.um, a.quantity
from Ingredient_sets a
join Ingredient_sets b 
  on a.recipe_id = b.recipe_id
 and a.ingred_id = b.ingred_id
 and a.um = b.um
 and a.quantity = b.quantity
```

Comment: The problem is that I have to show the 2 ingredients like column1:ingredient 1 column2: ingredient 2

Comment: @SzékelyRéka The question is no longer clear to me. Please include [in the question] a few rows of sample data and the expected result.